# Does GIT have an equivalent of Visual Sourcesafe's (project label)?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019, visual-sourcesafe-2005

VSS has a feature that allows one to create a (label) for an entire project or an entire solution.
The VSS (label) is typically the assembly or file version - example (1.0.0.1)

By creating a (label) in VSS I am able to view the label history and retrieve or get back to the exact same code base, and **all of the code files**, that were used to create a particular EXE.

My question is does GIT have a similar feature?  If so, how does one create a (project label) using GIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `git tag`.
Check out the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging).

Basically, with git tag you are able to specify a point in your history that signifies a "release" with a version of your software. For that tag of your source code you can create your corresponding `.exe` or whatever else you have.

There are two types of tags(labels) in git - lightweight and annotated.

A simple way to create a tag for your major release is

```
# annotated
git tag -a 1.0.6.0 -m "release 1.0.6.0"

# lightweight 
git tag v1.5.6
```

Annotated tags store more information and cannot be moved (but can be deleted). You can have many such tags indicating your multiple versions, while lightweight tags are like a branch, just a pointer to some state.